# Getting all nested data object using facets with Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

Greatings,

I have done some searching around but I have not come across a solid answer. We are using elastic search and trying to use facets to group together nested objects. Here is what the data looks like:

```
    {
    id:1,
    name:abc,
    object:{
        tag: 5,
        name:'test1',
        set: true
id
    }
},
{
    id:2,
    name:def,
    object:{
        tag: 2,
        name:'test2',
        set: false
    }
}
```

and I want to use facets to get a count of object nested. I can get one field from the object  using something like this:

```
{"facets":{"tags":{"terms":{"field":"object.name"}}}}'
```

but that just gets me the name and a count from the parent object its in. I want all the properties within object. I want tag,name and set to come back within the facet.

Is this possible? All signs seem to point to no, or to use something like script, where i can create a composite field of all 3, but that would require post processing, which i was hoping to avoid doing.

Any help would surely be appreciated. Thank you in advance.